# RegEx to insert spaces between (Number-Number), (Number-char), (Char-Special char) and (special char- char) except '\'

Tags: python, regex, text, nlp, python-re

I have written a code to clean the `LaTex` (Just a string) where I want to insert spaces among the nnumbers to tokenize the string. My code is as below:

```
def insert_spaces(sentence):
  '''
  Add a space around special characters, number and digits. So "2x+y -1/3x" becomes: "2 x + y - 1 / 3 x"
  '''
  dummy_list = []
  splitted_sent = list(sentence)
    
  for i in range(len(splitted_sent)-1):
    dummy_list.append(splitted_sent[i])
    
    if splitted_sent[i].isalpha(): # if it is an alphabet
      if splitted_sent[i+1].isdigit() or (not splitted_sent[i+1].isalnum()):
        dummy_list.append(' ')
    
    elif splitted_sent[i].isdigit(): # if it is a number
      if splitted_sent[i+1].isalpha() or (not splitted_sent[i+1].isalnum()):
        dummy_list.append(' ')
        
    elif (not splitted_sent[i].isalnum()) and (splitted_sent[i] not in [' ','\\']): # if it is a special char but not ' ' already
      if splitted_sent[i+1].isalnum():
        dummy_list.append(' ')
        
  dummy_list.append(splitted_sent[-1])
  
  return ''.join(dummy_list)
```

For Example, if my original query is:

```
'ds^{2} = (1 - {qcos\\theta\\over r})^{2\\over 1 + \\alpha^{2}}\\lbrace dr^2+r^2d\\theta^2+r^2sin^2\\theta d\\varphi^2\\rbrace -{dt^2\\over  (1 - {qcos\\theta\\over r})^{2\\over 1 + \\alpha^{2}}}\\, .\\label{eq:sps1} \\widetilde\\gamma_{\\rm hopf}\\simeq\\sum_{n>0}\\widetilde{G}_n{(-a)^n\\over2^{2n-1}}\\label{H4}3455'
```

then I want it cleaned as:

```
'd s ^ { 2 } = ( 1  - { q c o s \\theta \\over  r } ) ^ { 2 \\over  1  + \\alpha ^ { 2 } } \\lbrace  d r ^ 2 + r ^ 2 d \\theta ^ 2 + r ^ 2 sin ^ 2 \\theta  d \\varphi ^ 2 \\rbrace  -{ d t ^ 2 \\over   ( 1  - { q c o s \\theta \\over  r } ) ^ { 2 \\over  1  + \\alpha ^ { 2 } } } \\ , . \\label { eq : sps 1 } \\widetilde \\gamma _ { \\rm  h o p f } \\simeq \\sum _ { n > 0 } \\widetilde { G } _ n { ( - a ) ^ n \\over 2 ^ { 2 n - 1 } } \\label { H 4 } 3 4 5 5'
```

[The above result is a product of this this script](https://github.com/ritheshkumar95/im2latex-tensorflow/blob/master/im2markup/scripts/preprocessing/preprocess_formulas.py) which basically calls [this `KaTex` script](https://github.com/ritheshkumar95/im2latex-tensorflow/blob/master/im2markup/scripts/preprocessing/preprocess_latex.js)

But right now, I am getting my results as:

```
'ds ^{ 2 } = ( 1  - { qcos \\theta \\over  r })^{ 2 \\over  1  + \\alpha ^{ 2 }}\\lbrace  dr ^ 2 + r ^ 2 d \\theta ^ 2 + r ^ 2 sin ^ 2 \\theta  d \\varphi ^ 2 \\rbrace  -{ dt ^ 2 \\over   ( 1  - { qcos \\theta \\over  r })^{ 2 \\over  1  + \\alpha ^{ 2 }}}\\, .\\label { eq : sps 1 } \\widetilde \\gamma _{\\rm  hopf }\\simeq \\sum _{ n > 0 }\\widetilde { G }_ n {(- a )^ n \\over 2 ^{ 2 n - 1 }}\\label { H 4 } 3455'
```

Is there any way of achieving the same with the help of RegEx?

Comment: Your desired output seems to also be converting `\\over` to `frac`? Could you provide some more information regarding the transformation that you are trying to apply?

Comment: That is the only code that I used from the repo itself. For now, I'll just update the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

you have some nasty irregularities in your expected output, e.g.

- irregular extra whitespace
- `{eq:sps1}` that you'd like to output as `{ eq : sps 1 }`)
- `sin` which contrary to all other words (such as `q c o s`) should stay together as `sin` and not be converted to `s i n`
- `-{` at some point that did not get converted to `- {` as i'd expect

these exceptions defy any regex i was able to come up with during my testing. but this is pretty close to what you are trying to achieve, maybe you find it useful as a starting point...

**Update:** changed the expected result according to comments, fixed

- `sin` -> `s i n`
- `-{` -> `- {`

apart from whitespace this regex should handle *your example*. be aware that due to your description, e.g. `eq:...` is part of the regex to keep `eq` and `sqs` together as you asked.

```
import re

text = r'ds^{2} = (1 - {qcos\\theta\\over r})^{2\\over 1 + \\alpha^{2}}\\lbrace dr^2+r^2d\\theta^2+r^2sin^2\\theta d\\varphi^2\\rbrace -{dt^2\\over  (1 - {qcos\\theta\\over r})^{2\\over 1 + \\alpha^{2}}}\\, .\\label{eq:sps1} \\widetilde\\gamma_{\\rm hopf}\\simeq\\sum_{n>0}\\widetilde{G}_n{(-a)^n\\over2^{2n-1}}\\label{H4}3455'

# updated version according to comments, fixed in expected result:
# * "sin" -> "s i n"
# * "-{" -> "- {"
#expected = r'd s ^ { 2 } = ( 1  - { q c o s \\theta \\over  r } ) ^ { 2 \\over  1  + \\alpha ^ { 2 } } \\lbrace  d r ^ 2 + r ^ 2 d \\theta ^ 2 + r ^ 2 sin ^ 2 \\theta  d \\varphi ^ 2 \\rbrace  -{ d t ^ 2 \\over   ( 1  - { q c o s \\theta \\over  r } ) ^ { 2 \\over  1  + \\alpha ^ { 2 } } } \\ , . \\label { eq : sps 1 } \\widetilde \\gamma _ { \\rm  h o p f } \\simeq \\sum _ { n > 0 } \\widetilde { G } _ n { ( - a ) ^ n \\over 2 ^ { 2 n - 1 } } \\label { H 4 } 3 4 5 5'
expected = r'd s ^ { 2 } = ( 1  - { q c o s \\theta \\over  r } ) ^ { 2 \\over  1  + \\alpha ^ { 2 } } \\lbrace  d r ^ 2 + r ^ 2 d \\theta ^ 2 + r ^ 2 s i n ^ 2 \\theta  d \\varphi ^ 2 \\rbrace  - { d t ^ 2 \\over   ( 1  - { q c o s \\theta \\over  r } ) ^ { 2 \\over  1  + \\alpha ^ { 2 } } } \\ , . \\label { eq : sps 1 } \\widetilde \\gamma _ { \\rm  h o p f } \\simeq \\sum _ { n > 0 } \\widetilde { G } _ n { ( - a ) ^ n \\over 2 ^ { 2 n - 1 } } \\label { H 4 } 3 4 5 5'

res = re.sub(r"(?<!\s)(\s*(?:\\\\[a-zA-Z]*)|eq(?=:)|(?<=:)[a-zA-Z]+|(?:[^\s]))", r' \1', text).strip()
print(re.sub(r'\s+', r' ', res))
print(re.sub(r'\s+', r' ', expected))
```

output:

```
d s ^ { 2 } = ( 1 - { q c o s \\theta \\over r } ) ^ { 2 \\over 1 + \\alpha ^ { 2 } } \\lbrace d r ^ 2 + r ^ 2 d \\theta ^ 2 + r ^ 2 s i n ^ 2 \\theta d \\varphi ^ 2 \\rbrace - { d t ^ 2 \\over ( 1 - { q c o s \\theta \\over r } ) ^ { 2 \\over 1 + \\alpha ^ { 2 } } } \\ , . \\label { eq : sps 1 } \\widetilde \\gamma _ { \\rm h o p f } \\simeq \\sum _ { n > 0 } \\widetilde { G } _ n { ( - a ) ^ n \\over 2 ^ { 2 n - 1 } } \\label { H 4 } 3 4 5 5
d s ^ { 2 } = ( 1 - { q c o s \\theta \\over r } ) ^ { 2 \\over 1 + \\alpha ^ { 2 } } \\lbrace d r ^ 2 + r ^ 2 d \\theta ^ 2 + r ^ 2 s i n ^ 2 \\theta d \\varphi ^ 2 \\rbrace - { d t ^ 2 \\over ( 1 - { q c o s \\theta \\over r } ) ^ { 2 \\over 1 + \\alpha ^ { 2 } } } \\ , . \\label { eq : sps 1 } \\widetilde \\gamma _ { \\rm h o p f } \\simeq \\sum _ { n > 0 } \\widetilde { G } _ n { ( - a ) ^ n \\over 2 ^ { 2 n - 1 } } \\label { H 4 } 3 4 5 5
```

Comment: No Actually `sin` becomes `s i n` because there can be `sinx`, `siny`..etc etc and my vocab would blow up. But I'm sorry for the spacings as I did change then only here manually. Yes you are correct regarding what I was trying to achieve except `sin` etc

Comment: Also, there's one more thing that I missed. I want to remove anything inside `final \text { whatever here } result` including `\text`. so it becomes `final result`. What could be used here? a stand Alone example.

Comment: I have not answered your second question, as I saw you have already posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67640363/12693728 (please ask a single question at a time and do not mix or change them entirely). I assume the solutions provided there should solve your problem, otherwise please elaborate your question in the other thread.