# Regex pattern to remove anything \text {whatever here}

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I can use `\{\%(.*?)\%\}` to change `hell0 {% my text  %}` to `hello`

or `<!--.*?/-->` to change `useful (<!-- remove it /-->)useful`  to `useful useful`

My problem is that I want to remove anything inside `final \text { whatever here } result` including `\text`. so it becomes `final result`.

I tried the same method as `r"\\text .*?/ }"` but that did not work.

I have a code  whic is part of a class that cleans my data:

```
def get_features(self,s:str)->list:
        '''
        Produce Shingles or n-Grams of CHARACTERS in a given string.
        args:
            s: Given String
        out: Shingle os a string. If a string is 'how are you' then the returned list is ['how','owa','war','are','rey','eyo','you',] with width = 3
        '''
        assert self.args_flag, "pass in the arguments for preprocessing by calling set_preprocess_params()"
        
        if self.lower:
            s = s.lower()
            
        if self.ascii_only:
            s = re.sub(r"[^\x00-\x7F]",'',s)

        if self.remove_special: # Remove special characters
            s = re.sub(r'[^\w ]+', '', s)
    
        s = re.sub(r'[_ \\]', '', s) # Remove Empty spaces and _ as they are not covered in special chars. Also, I want to remove any "backslashes \"
        return s
```

Comment: Does `re.sub(r'\s*\\text\s*{[^{}]*}', '', s)` help solve the problem?

Comment: `re.sub('(?<=final )(.*)(?=result)', '', 'final \text { whatever here } result')`?

Comment: Could you please review the answers below and  provide feedback?

Answer (score 2):

If you have no `{` and `}` in between braces you can use Python `re` this way:

```py
re.sub(r'\s*\\text\s*{[^{}]*}', '', s)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/JbKI0y/1/).
Here, `\s*\\text\s*{[^{}]*}` matches

- `\s*` - zero  or more whitespace chars
- `\\` - a `\` char
- `text` - `text` string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace
- `{[^{}]*}` - `{`, any zero or more chars other than `{` and `}` and then a `}`.

If you need to match nested braces, you need to install the PyPi `regex` module (run `pip install regex` in the terminal) and then use

```py
import regex
#...
text = regex.sub(r'\s*\\text\s*({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})', '', text)
```

See the [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/JbKI0y/3/). Here,

- `\s*\\text\s*` - matches `\text` enclosed with optional whitespace
- `({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})` - Group 1:

  - `{` - a  `{` char
  - `(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*` - zero or more occurrences of either one or more chars other than `{` and `}` or the whole Group 1 pattern recursed
  - `}` - a `}` char.

See a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##bY7NCsIwEITvPsUSKCStiOJNkD6IUaiwmkL6wzbVlnWfPfYHPHkYGIZvhmnH4Jr6GGNZtQ0FIHzisAk4BDiDcuj9HjiBaoQlg0Rs/SjrwoO1S8LwdkXAFxI4JASZJrrehz8YzxyjkAA7ZBKUH642LZV10OuBXdffNSnbpWt9Mpp1frrcWK5Z9tH5wZhUjNqCmjQjBkyMXw) online.

Comment: This should be it, also as the OP tries `r"\\text` to match `\text`

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below regex:

```
s = re.sub(r" \text .*}", '', s)
```

Couple examples:

```
>>> strg = "final \text {de2mflkmlkfm;rl;erv,;g ,;lgmkl4324254^;2~^^^&&#343141fg 125t5 4$##%#234tg lkg k;kl} result"
>>> re.sub(r" \text .*}", '', strg)
'final result'

>>> strg = "final \text {balh blah 1 2 12, equi445; code22****...} result"
>>> re.sub(r" \text .*}", '', strg)
'final result'

>>> strg = "final \text {{.}swdwwqw {}}. } qdd{{}}} dqqq uit(q.}} result"
>>> re.sub(r" \text .*}", '', strg)
'final result'
```

Comment: The answer is wrong. The `\t` in `r" \text .*}"` regex is a TAB matching pattern, it does not match a backslash and `t`. Your `strg` example string literals also contain a TAB, making an illusion it works. Also,  `.*` will match greedily till the last `}`, deleting too much in case there are two matches on a line. You can't rely on greedy dot in such cases.

Comment: Well wasn't that the requirement of OP?  Match till the last `}` followed by space and `result`. Please read the question again.

Comment: Yes, please do read it again, there is no mentioning of matching till *last* `}`. Once there are two `\text` (that your regex does not match) on a line, your `.*` will grab the text between two matches that will also get removed. But it won't anyway since your regex does not match the text OP has.

Comment: How is it clear that `\t` in `\text` is backslash and `t`, and not TAB ?  OP says he wants to remove `\text`, how do you interpret it is only backslash , a`t` and 'ext' ?